# Read Epub Files using HTML and Javascript from Android Asset folder?

Tags: android, jquery, html, epub

I want to read the EPUB files which are located in Assets folder. I have a HTML file. In which i have referred epub.min.js and provided a epub file location to read the file. But the epub file was not loaded. Can anyone suggest me how to read epub files using html and javascript in Android?

**File Locations**

```
Asset/Sample/index.html
Asset/sample/epub.min.js
Asset/Sample/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
Asset/Sample/Epub file folder. All html, images are available in this folder

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head> 
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Render -->
            <script src="epub.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">    
        var book = ePub("Azure_Cosmos_DB_and_DocumentDB_Succinctly/");
          $(document).ready(function () {
          book.renderTo("area");
        });        
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="main">
    <div id="prev" onclick="book.prevPage()" style="font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;" class="arrow">‹</div>
    <div id="area" style="height:500px;"></div>
    <div id="next" onclick="book.nextPage()" style="font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;" class="arrow">›</div>    
</div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JellyBean)
{
 webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true; 
 webView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
}
```

Also please keep the script files directly in asset folder instead of keeping to inner folders.